# Stored Procedure Failing to Insert to a Table, No Errors Given

Tags: stored-procedures, server, ssms, azure-sql-database

Im working on an azure database just adding a couple of Stored Procedures and just making sure the program I'm building with it in .NET is all aligned properly.

I'm not going to go into the Stored Procedure itself nor the Program I'm developing because I don't believe the problem is there, I have a Development program and database which is using the exact same code and they work fine, I'm using Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio to handle everything on the servers side.

The only difference to the current setup is that I myself scripted a bunch of the Stored procedures and a single View of a table that I did not create....(I did not create the table, but I made a view for it which is a slightly different format)

The person creating most of these databases and table is one of the database administrators I guess (not Microsoft, but an employee of the company using their services), I on the other hand am a freelance programmer and I'm guessing I have somewhat limited access to the server (limited credentials).....although it's allowing me to do more or less anything I need to do like creating SP's etc.

My current (and only problem) is a single stored procedure that runs through without an error does not update the table (the table i did not create) the Stored Procedure just inserts a couple of records and then deletes a record from the same table.......

It deletes the record just fine but for some reason the INSERT doesn't insert anything.

Again, this works fine on another Development database and the programs are sending the exact same strings but this new database just doesn't want to play along.....

Could this be a permission problem I'm having between my stored procedure and the table I did not create?

I would love to dump this onto the admin guy (and already did but he dumped it back on me haha) so I just want to be sure I'm not wasting his time....... and give him something solid to go on.

Thanks for your help Paul S.

Comment: is there a trigger on the table?

Comment: No i dont think so, this issue has actually being resolved just recently, im still waiting for some feedback as to what happened, ill post it when i know :).